# Temperature is not updated on OLED screen - Grove components

Tags: temperature-sensor, arduino-zero, oled

I am using 2 grove components in order to display a temperature. I use an [I2C High Accuracy Temperature Sensor - MCP9808](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Grove-I2C-High-Accuracy-Temperature-Sensor-MCP9808.html) and an [OLED Screen](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Grove-OLED-Yellow-Blue-Display-0-96-SSD1315-V1-0-p-5010.html) using this script:

```
#include <U8g2lib.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Seeed_MCP9808.h"

MCP9808 sensor;
U8G2_SSD1306_128X64_NONAME_F_SW_I2C u8g2(U8G2_R0, /* clock=*/SCL, /* data=*/SDA, /* reset=*/U8X8_PIN_NONE);  //Software I2C

char strTemp\[16\];
float temp;

void setup() {
  u8g2.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  if (sensor.init()) {
    Serial.println("sensor init failed!!");
  }   
  sensor.set_config(SET_CONFIG_ADDR, 0x0008);
  Serial.println("sensor init!!");
}

void loop() {
  sensor.get_temp(&temp);
  Serial.print("temperature value is: ");
  Serial.println(temp);
  delay(1000);

  dtostrf(temp, 7, 2, strTemp);

  u8g2.clearBuffer();                   // clear the internal memory
  u8g2.setFont(u8g2_font_luBIS08_tf);   // choose a suitable font
  u8g2.drawStr(0, 10, "Hello Seeed!");  // write something to the internal memory
  u8g2.drawStr(0, 30, "Temp. value:");  // write something to the internal memory
  u8g2.drawStr(0, 50, strTemp);         // write something to the internal memory
  u8g2.sendBuffer();                    // transfer internal memory to the display
}
```

The temperature output is not updated on the screen and I think it might be related to I2C addresses. Is it possible?

I run an I2C scanner and I think that the OLED address is 0x3C and the temp. sensor is 0x18. How can I assign them correctly. I never done something like that so any help is welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Simplify the problem.  Try making a copy of your software w/o the OLED code and simply print the temperature out to the serial monitor already part of the IDE.  If that works, then it may be the I2C addressing.  If it does not then it's likely how you are sampling the temperature sensor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and recommendation. Without the OLED code it prints the temperature out to the serial monitor, Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: does "Hello Seeed!" show on the display?

Comment: @jsotola: Yes, it does appear on the display

Comment: ... oh, I see you are already printing out the temperature.  I'd still comment out all the u8g2 lines and maybe even remove the OLED hardware and see if you see new temperature data ever second.

Comment: "...Without the OLED code it prints the temperature out to the serial monitor...", yes, but does it print out a new temperature every second?  If so, my guess is that the libraries are not working well w/each other.  Likely they are trying to use the same I2C processor hardware and braking it for the other library.

Comment: @st2000: When removing all the u8g2 lines I see in the serial monitor the temp. When  the u8g2 lines are in the code  even the serial monitor is not working

Comment: st2000: I suspect as well that there is I2C interference. Any idea how to change one or both of them?

Comment: You can look at the [MPC9808](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Grove_Temperature_sensor_MCP9808) and  [U8G2](https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2/wiki) code on github (not sure about if I got the correct U8G2 web page) and try to design a version of code that are compatible w/one another.  But 1st I'd look for other's w/similar problems.  For all we know, maybe the U8G2 libaray has an option to skip I2C initialization already built in.

Comment: Or, you could check if your specific Arduino platform has a second I2C port and use it for the U8G2 display.  Or you could buy an Arduino w/2 or more I2C ports (but check to make sure the libraries you are using are compatible with the new Arduino).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mix software I2C with hardware I2C on the hardware I2C pins.

To use hw I2C with the display use the U8G2_SSD1306_128X64_NONAME_F_**HW**_I2C constructor.

```
U8G2_SSD1306_128X64_NONAME_F_HW_I2C u8g2(U8G2_R0, /* reset=*/U8X8_PIN_NONE);
```

Or use a different pair of pins for the software I2C display control.